# If a sample is normally distributed, does it mean a subsample is normally distributed, too?

Tags: normal-distribution

Let's say I have sample of the size 800.000. All the test says it's normally distributed, and a fitted distribution looks very nice on the data. I take a subsample of it (like 10.000 records). Can I say they are normally distributed too? My intuition says they are, since the subsample is infered from a normal distribution, too. I take subsamples a lot of times, so I would not want to do the test every time.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you subsample randomly and uniformly?  If so, then *a fortiori* your subsample was drawn randomly from a Normal distribution.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/442016/if-a-sample-is-not-normally-distributed-can-a-subset-of-the-sample-be-normal

Comment: @whuber, yes the subsample was sampled randomly with replacement. That's what I thought, thanks!

Comment: Well, if you are truly nitpicky, then sampling with replacement will give you a non-normal distribution, because you have a nonzero probability of seeing the exact same observation twice, and such an event has zero probability for continuous distributions. But for practical purposes, you can probably disregard this

Comment: randomly subsample without replacement would be much better from a theoretical perspective